# How to delete the bot's previous message on discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have seen this command

```
@bot.command()
async def disappear(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hey!")
    await msg.delete(delay=1)
```

However, I'm trying to delete the "msg" in some other function. To be precise, this is my code

```
@bot.command()
async def disappear(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send("Hey!")
    await msg.delete(delay=1)

@bot.command()
async def somethingelse(ctx):
    await msg.delete(delay=1)
```

which gives me an error

```
 NameError: name 'msg' is not defined
```

So i wanted to know if there is any method where it is possible to delete the bot's previous message by the bot itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
prev_msg = None

@bot.command()
async def deleteprevmsg(ctx):
    global prev_msg

    try:
        await prev_msg.delete(delay = 1)
    except:
        prev_msg = await ctx.send("No previous message found")
```

And put `prev_msg =`  before every `await ctx.send()`. Remember to `global prev_msg` in every function that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use globals, you can get last message sent by your bot in that channel then delete it.

```
@client.command()
async def somethingelse(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(123456789123456)  # ID of channel
    msg = await channel.history().get(author__id=123456789123456)  # ID of bot
    await msg.delete(delay=1)
    print(f"Deleted message: {msg.id}")
```

[`channel.history()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel%20history#discord.TextChannel.history)

Comment: This bot will be used in multiple server channels. So how do I get the channel ID?